# How to return value from drop down in javascript without further button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Return value from drop down in javascript(with a button click) is successful
but how to do without button click after drop down select?just return value on change select value.

JS

```
function getCity() {
    var x = document.getElementById("home_city_select").value;
    var xx=$("#home_city_select").val();
    alert(xx);
}
```

HTML

```
<select name="home_city_select" id="home_city_select" data-icon="carat-d" style="width:auto;">
<option value="select_city" style="font-family: Comic Sans MS; font-weight: bold" selected>Select City</option>
                    <option value="Kolkata">Kolkata</option>
                    <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
                    <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
                    <option value="Bengaluru">Bengaluru</option>
....
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="getCity()">OK</button>
```

Also tried this but no value returning

```
$('#home_city_select').on('change', function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        val   = $this.val();
    alert('onChange = ' + val);
});
$('#the-page').on('click', '.ui-selectmenu-list > li', function () {
    alert('onClick = ' + $('#home_city_select').children().eq($(this).attr('data-option-index')).val());
});
```

Comment: Can you try dropdown **change()** event in jquery?

Comment: got success with onchange="getCity()" in select tag.

Comment: if you use jquery why you mixed this with native js???